# How we can handle nested hierarchy

Tags: sql, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have below data and need to populate new column having only Master Parent ID i.e.6

```
Child ID     Parent ID   Master Parent ID
1             2           6
2             3           6
3             4           6
4             5           6
5             6           6
6             6           6
```

I tried using below update query to update Master Parent ID

```
UPDATE table dummy t1
SET t1.Master_Parent_ID = t2.Parent_ID
FROM table dummy t2    
WHERE t1.Parent_ID = t2.Child_id
```

But this is giving me below results

```
Child ID     Parent ID   Master Parent ID
1             2           3
2             3           4
3             4           5
4             5           6
5             6           6
6             6           6
```

Can someone please guide how achieve the desired result

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: Maybe node #6 should not have parent as ifselt.